# How to supply C# application with data from a text file?

Tags: c#

I have a text file data.txt which has this data on it:

```
5 5
1 2 N
LMLMLMLMM
3 3 E
MMRMMRMRRM
```

My application can read the data from the file:

```
System.IO.StreamReader = dataFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("C\\data.txt");
string myData = dataFile.ReadToEnd();
```

And I can split the string:

```
Array splitString = myData.Split(' ');
```

Now I want to use the splitted string as values on my program, like this:

```
     Grid viewGrid = new Grid(Coordinates(5,5));
     viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(1,2,'N',"LMLMLMLMM"));
     viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(3,3,'E',"MMRMMRMRRM"));
```

Comment: and what problem do you have?

Comment: Rov? I am presuming that is Row?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the splittes string as values for the application, the values on the question are hard coded and I have to get them from a text file @sine

Comment: No Rov is not a row but an object of another class @Andrew

Comment: @Thando.  I'd maybes think about changing the name of your class then because that is extremely confusing!

Comment: I'll do that, thanks @Andrew

Comment: You hav newlines added?? why didn't you show code splitting using '\n'  ??

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like

```
List<string> Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);

string[] coordLine = Data[0].Split(' ');
Grid viewGrid = new Grid(Coordinates(int.Parse(coordLine [0]), int.Parse(coordLine [1]));

for (int i = 1; i < Data.Count / 2; i++)
{
    string[] line1 = Data[2 * i - 1].Split(' ');
    string line2 = Data[2 * i];

    viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(Int32.Parse(line1[0]), Int32.Parse(line1[1]), line1[2], line2));
}
```

This works or any odd number of lines (one line for coordinates and pairs for your objects).

Comment: Where does 'file' come from?

Comment: `System.IO.File` (`ReadAllLines()`is a static method of that class, I edited the answer accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

In case your text file is always in the same format you can easily use the string array and hardcode the order of the appearing elements. To convert the strings to numbers you can use `Int32.Parse('1')`.

```
Grid viewGrid = new Grid(Coordinates(Int32.Parse(splitString[0]), Int32.Parse(splitString[1])));
viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(Int32.Parse(splitString[2]), Int32.Parse(splitString[3]), splitString[4], splitString[5]));
viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(Int32.Parse(splitString[6]), Int32.Parse(splitString[7]), splitString[8], splitString[9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid viewGrid = new Grid(Coordinates(int.Parse(splitString[0]), int.Parse(splitString[1])));
viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Row(int.Parse(splitString[2]), int.Parse(splitString[3]),splitString[4],splitString[5]));
viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Row(int.Parse(splitString[6]), int.Parse(splitString[7]),splitString[8],splitString[9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array splitString = myData.Split('\n');
        Array cords = splitString[0].ToString().Split(' ');
        int cordX = Convert.ToInt32(cords[0]);
        int cordY = Convert.ToInt32(cords[1]);

        Grid viewGrid = new Grid(Coordinates(cordX, cordY));

        for (int i = 1; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            Array nxtSplit = splitString[i].ToString().Split(' ');
            int x = int.Parse(nxtSplit[0]);
            int y = int.Parse(nxtSplit[1]);
            char c = Convert.ToChar(nxtSplit[2]);
            i++;
            string s = splitString[i].ToString();
            viewGrid.AddToCollection(new Rov(x, y, c, s));
        }
```